# Is "spellbind" a defective verb?

Tags: word-usage, verbs

A *defective verb* is one that doesn't have all the usual forms, e.g. "*give*", "*gives*", "*giving*", "*gave*", "*given*" are forms of a non-defective verb.

I  had thought the only defective verbs in English are modal auxiliary verbs; thus:

> Today he **can** do that. (simple present)
>   Yesterday he **could** do that. (simple past)
>   Often he ***has been able** to do that.

English doesn't allow "**He has could**" or the like.
We speak of "**being able**" and not "**canning**", and we say

> "He **will be able**"
>   instead of
>   "He **will can**." 
>   <sup>(In the Carolinas however, it is perfectly standard to say "He might can do that.")</sup>

The words "*spellbinding*", "*spellbound*", and "*spellbinder*" appear to be standard but does one ever see the simple present form "*spellbind*", or the future "*will spellbind*", or even "*spellbinding*" as a part of a compound verb rather than as an adjective?

Should this be considered a defective verb or maybe not even a verb at all?

It seems odd that one of the missing verb forms is the one that would presumably be lemmatic.

Comment: spellbind is usually used in ***the passive voice***: to be spellbound by something. The  movie is spellbinding [on the audience]. He was spellbound by the speaker's words. Or adjectivally: The spellbinding words had a huge impact on him.

Comment: [will spellbind](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&ei=4uI9WNbDPIjT0gKdhrfwDg&q="will+spellbind"+-"and+will+spellbind+everyone")  ... [spellbinds](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q="spellbinds"+), which can only be simple present.

Comment: @Lambie: I'm not sure: in sentences like the one you gave, is it really the passive voice, or is the copula and a predicative adjective?

Comment: @sumelic 'was spellbound.' is probably better treated as using the adjective, but 'was spellbound by N' seems far more verby.

Comment: *Spellbind* appears in present simple, past simple, past participle, gerund-participle and plain forms. It isn't defective.

Comment: I agree it is not defective. But in English, it is usually used in a passive sense. He was spellbound by the speech is not an adjective. The movie is spellbinding on the audience is not an adjective.

Comment: @Lambie : "It is a spellbinding film." seems like a commonplace usage.

Comment: @Michael Hardy Yes, it is. And it is an adjective in that commonplace usage, isn't it?

Comment: @Lambie : ok, So maybe it's defective verb that has _none_ of the possible verb forms. "Spellbound" and "spellbinding" and "spellbinder" have forms that appear to be derived from a verb, "spellbind", but one doesn't see it, or its forms, being used as verbs.

Answer (score 3):

"There was a class of men regularly set apart to bless and curse, **to spellbind** the winds and foretell events." [Sermons Preached at Trinity Chapel](https://books.google.com/books?id=1J5TAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA38&dq=%22spellbind%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjlobGC4fbQAhWsLMAKHcpVBfcQ6AEIJDAC#v=onepage&q=%22spellbind%22&f=false) 25 January 1852

"But, nevertheless, we have idols that hold the people captive — entrance and **spellbind** them with the witchery of their charms, and wrap them" [American States, Churches, and the War](https://books.google.com/books?id=2Jw9AAAAYAAJ&pg=PA525&dq=%22spellbind%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjlobGC4fbQAhWsLMAKHcpVBfcQ6AEIQTAH#v=onepage&q=%22spellbind%22&f=false) 1865

"A superlative Hebrew Conjuror, **spellbinding** all the great Lords, great Parties, great Interests of England, to his hand in this manner, and leading them by the nose, like helpless mesmerised somnambulant cattle..." [Critical and miscellaneous essays](https://books.google.com/books?id=VS81AQAAMAAJ&pg=PA597&dq=%22spellbinding%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwip95694vbQAhVZGsAKHbwsA-YQ6AEINDAF#v=onepage&q=%22spellbinding%22&f=false) 1888

"But if they are not careful he **will spell-bind** and trance-chain them as completely when he shall thunder..." [A Speech on the Present Duties and Future Destiny of the Negro Race](https://books.google.com/books?id=Qy4t_ttY2v4C&pg=PA27&dq=will%20spellbind&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiMh6f64vbQAhWlHsAKHVBLCqoQ6AEIHDAA#v=onepage&q=will%20spellbind&f=false) 2 September 1872

"As an orator he **will spellbind** where Phillips or Prentiss would have bored." [Watson's Magazine, Volume 2](https://books.google.com/books?id=BE5TAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA15&dq=%22will%20spellbind%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiq4PXO4_bQAhVjLcAKHSnECPsQ6AEIPTAH#v=onepage&q=%22will%20spellbind%22&f=false) July 1905

Rare, but definitely examples out there of all the forms.

Answer (score 3):

Interestingly, some writers have used *spellbounded* as a past tense form, suggesting that they view *spellbound* (not *spellbind*) as the present-tense form. For example, from [*The Postal Record*](https://books.google.com/books?id=645ZAAAAYAAJ&q=%22spellbounded%22&dq=%22spellbounded%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjM6IW16_bQAhUL9mMKHQqvDfg4ChDoAQhGMAk) (1985):

> First District Congressman Charlie Hayes **spellbounded** the convention with his wit, poise and knowledge of letter carrier concerns.

From Mary Ann Harrell, [*Surprising Lands Down Under*](https://books.google.com/books?id=CTvDZ7wg78QC&q=%22spellbounded%22&dq=%22spellbounded%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiEp9zv6_bQAhUD82MKHZFxB-84FBDoAQgnMAM) (1989):

> I asked a veteran coach driver there what single spot the tourists liked best. "Ah, Mount Cook," he replied, "she **spellbounded** them when she came out!" Much of the time she stays in, in the long white cloud that often cloaks the highlands..

From Bill Pemstein, [*A Stone's Throw*](https://books.google.com/books?id=IYRGAwAAQBAJ&pg=PA14&dq=%22spellbounded%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjK4I_L6PbQAhVB-2MKHR68BIEQ6AEIMDAE#v=onepage&q=%22spellbounded%22&f=false) (2011):

> On March 20, Stone again took on the Texas Rangers and **spellbounded** them for four innings. A six-run fifth inning drove him out. A two-run wind-blown homer from Bump Wills was the key blow.

From Stefan Dumitrescu, [*You'll Be Ether, Too, Beyond the World*](https://books.google.com/books?id=0bfZCQAAQBAJ&pg=PT34&dq=%22spellbounded%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjK4I_L6PbQAhVB-2MKHR68BIEQ6AEIITAB#v=onepage&q=%22spellbounded%22&f=false) (2015):

> The one who **spellbounded** the heart of famaous Iancu Delamare, merchant and lawyer who was proverbial for being a Casanova and a man with mysterious powers, was the daughter of a chief governor of Moldova, who had the home in Braila, because, having large estates, he was dealing with the grain, fur and fish trade.

From S. Vijay Palaniappan, [*Chocolate Sundae Fudge: The Embrace of the Entwined Game*](https://books.google.com/books?id=0Z_XCwAAQBAJ&pg=PT50&dq=%22spellbounded%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjK4I_L6PbQAhVB-2MKHR68BIEQ6AEIQDAH#v=onepage&q=%22spellbounded%22&f=false) (2016):

> She aid, 'To be kissed in the middle of the street in the pouring rain,' she amazed me by uttering this. I was **spellbounded** and was speechless for a while. Then I ardently said, 'I'll make that alive for you, my dear Rishita'.

Likewise, some authors have used *spellbounds* as the third-person singular form of "to spellbound." For example, from Joseph Kelner, [*Personal Injury: Successful Litifgation Techniques*](https://books.google.com/books?id=3LhGAQAAIAAJ&q=%22spellbounds%22&dq=%22spellbounds%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjHpu-U7vbQAhUW-GMKHU_1B4s4KBDoAQglMAM) (1964):

> The summation concludes with a lyrical story which **spellbounds** the jurors. Counsel impresses the jury with the importance of their task, while at the same time employing a subtle analogy. It is not difficult to equate the parties in this case with the people in the story.

From [*The East*](https://books.google.com/books?id=UqVwAAAAMAAJ&q=%22spellbounds%22&dq=%22spellbounds%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjHpu-U7vbQAhUW-GMKHU_1B4s4KBDoAQghMAI), volumes 18–19 (1982) [combined snippets]:

> This passage from his writing on aesthetics shows how strongly he was attracted to Tokushima: "It's easy to find artwork that **spellbounds**. Just walk through Tokushima city and the surrounding countryside. The tools in a gentle line at the shop, a ceramic teapot, a winding country road, a working farmer—everything is a work of art."

From Herbert Loebl, [*Government Factories and the Origins of British Regional Policy, 1934–1948*](https://books.google.com/books?id=VbMuAAAAMAAJ&q=%22spellbounds%22&dq=%22spellbounds%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjHpu-U7vbQAhUW-GMKHU_1B4s4KBDoAQgyMAY) (1988) [text not shown in snippet window]:

> The leading article in The Times of 20 March 1934 - the issue which opened the series - saw 'a background of bare justice behind the unyielding Socialism which **spellbounds** Durham Man today, because he thinks he can see no proof of ...

From Aśoka Jeratha, [*The Splendour of Himalayan Art and Culture*](https://books.google.com/books?id=IQDkxM0GTw4C&pg=PA120&dq=%22spellbounds%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiUrojX7PbQAhVB3mMKHVzAD1g4ChDoAQglMAM#v=onepage&q=%22spellbounds%22&f=false) (1995):

> The scene **spellbounds** the viewers capturing the lure of nature of the medieval times perpetuating with that of today. Its inner walls are the epitomes of the miraculous power of the beauty of line and colour, unfolding several chapters of history with manyfold sequences altercating with the modern times.

From India. Ministry of Information and Broadcasting, Publications Division, [*Freedom Fighters Remember*](https://books.google.com/books?id=3ghuAAAAMAAJ&q=%22spellbounds%22&dq=%22spellbounds%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjp8YGu7fbQAhUC42MKHWIHAXs4HhDoAQgZMAA) (1997) [combined snippets]:

> Shri Datta Mazumdar, still walks straight at the ripe age of 93, attends court and **spellbounds** all and sundry with his oration delivered in a stentorian voice. With a memory so sharp that would put any young man to shame, he still vividly recalls his days during the freedom movement and blasts off - "we have been cheated out of independence of undivided India!"

And similarly for *spellbounding*, from Adrian Jasper, "[Deadwood](https://books.google.com/books?id=OlNVDQAAQBAJ&pg=PT32&dq=%22spellbounding%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiO_f_n8fbQAhWCilQKHQZwDD44ChDoAQgZMAA#v=onepage&q=%22spellbounding%22&f=false)," in *Lady Muslim with a Pen: Poetry and Essays* (2012):

> Face like a sculpture, designed to a chisel./ A frame that wows, **spellbounding** with a sizzle:/ But “wow” turned to “whoa!” when he spoke, expounding the Ugliest sounds:/ From “spellbound” to “hellhound”...

And for the future form "will spellbound," from Ed Rosenthal, [*The Big Book of Buds: Marijuana Varieties from the World's Great*](https://books.google.com/books?id=-WsTuI271UEC&pg=PA141&dq=%22will+spellbound%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi0yJOt_fbQAhVGymMKHQ_OAVIQ6AEIJjAC#v=onepage&q=%22will%20spellbound%22&f=false) (2011):

> Named for the heroic woman in the Arabian legend, *The Thousand and One Nights*, Paradise's She[h]erazade will take considerably less time than the title implies, finishing in about 56 nights. In the legend, the character Sheherazade saves her own life using her exceptional storytelling skills that awe the King into sparing her life and eventually taking her as his Queen. The variety bearing her name **will spellbound** you with the promise of her potent, musky-sweet flowers, possibly making her the queen of your crop.

And for the infinitive "to spellbound," from [*Black Business Digest*](https://books.google.com/books?id=rq8RAQAAMAAJ&q=%22to+spellbound%22&dq=%22to+spellbound%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwitj-_a-_bQAhXBr1QKHVqvBdc4qgEQ6AEIJjAD) (1973):

> We have covered a lot of ground in a short period of time. My attempt here was not to try **to spellbound** you with some highly sophisticated financial lecture; but to try and get down to some of the nuts and bolts or the nitty gritty of what makes bankers tick, and what you have to do, to turn your banker on ...

Many of these instances are not the work of great literary stylists—although the excerpt that speaks of "chapters of history with manyfold sequences altercating with the modern times" is pretty hard to beat—but they do suggest a parallel (and rival) series of forms based on "to spellbound" in opposition to "to spellbind." Whether that indicates a double layer of verbal defectiveness or the linguistic equivalent of a largely uninhabited house is unclear to me.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably best not to analyze *spellbound* and *spellbinding* as forms of a defective verb.

People have used other forms of a verb *spellbind*. The verb is less common and less established than the forms "spellbinding", "spellbound", and "spellbinder" because "[incorporation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incorporation_(linguistics)#English)" in English occurs most commonly in agent nouns (like "babysitter") or departicipial adjectives (like "breastfed"); Wikipedia says that verbs with incorporation "are usually back-formations".

Aside from object and instrument incorporation, there are words like "downtrodden" that look like participles but don't have corresponding verbs (*"downtread" does not exist). These should probably be analyzed as departicipial adjectives, not as defective verbs.

There are some verbs that maybe have "defective" conjugations relating to past-participle forms, but very few, and it's not clear how best to analyze them. I wrote an answer the the question "[What are the defective verbs?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/460784/what-are-the-defective-verbs/460801#460801)" where I talk about *stride, strode, ?strode/stridden* and *be reputed* and *be rumo(u)red*.

Comment: As a counter-example to _breastfeeding_ (which in itself is interesting in that the verb is now far more common than the adjective), _spoon-feed_ is attested from the 1600s while _spoon-fed_ seems to come much later. (Also, _downtread_ does occur – and has occurred since the 1500s – but is of course quite rare. I was about to say that _heartbreak_ would be a better option, but apparently that gets used too. Still, I find _downtread_ fairly unremarkable, whereas I would definitely do a double-take at _to heartbreak someone_.)