# What are the defective verbs?

Tags: defective-verbs

Apart from modals what defective verbs exist?  For example beware and begone.

Comment: In the Carolinas one hears "We might can do that." Modal auxiliary verbs are somewhat less defective there than in most places.

Answer (score 4):

There aren't many defective verbs in English, but it's difficult to say exactly how many there are because some words might or might not be defective, depending on how willing you are to accept weird-sounding forms.

For example, various linguists seem to have noted that for many English speakers, nothing sounds natural as the past participle of the verb *stride.* ("I had *stridden/strode/strid?*") See this Language Log post: "[When you stride away, what is it that you've done?](http://languagelog.ldc.upenn.edu/nll/?p=737)", October 20, 2008, by Geoffrey K. Pullum, and this article: "[Transderivational relations and paradigm gaps in Russian verbs](https://www.glossa-journal.org/articles/10.5334/gjgl.59/print/)", by Katya Pertsova.

Pullum notes that the lack of an acceptable past participle form for *stride* feels more accidental than the lack of non-finite forms for modals, so even if they can both be described as "defective verbs", the reason *stride* lacks a past-participle form might be different from the reason modals lack a past-participle form.

"[A corpus study of some rare English verbs](http://www.skase.sk/Volumes/JTL29/pdf_doc/06.pdf)", by Laurie Bauer, mentions a few other possible candidates (as well as discussing some verbs that are definitely not defective, but that show variability in their conjugation). The ones that I found most convincing as possible defective verbs are *repute* and *rumo(u)r,* which most often occur in passive-looking constructions in the forms *reputed* and *rumo(u)red* (although I'm not sure how clearly we can establish that these are verb forms and not adjectives; see the question [Is "rumored" a verb or an adjective (a participle adjective)?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/449222/is-rumored-a-verb-or-an-adjective-a-participle-adjective)). However, it seems that at least a few speakers do find it acceptable to use *rumor* or *repute* as an active-voice verb.

Comment: "I strode away"? Sounds fine to me.

Comment: @Mitch That’s not perfect: asking what it is that you **have** done requires an answer of “I’**ve** X”, for [values of X uncomfortable](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22stridden%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en) to many of us, Strider perhaps excepted.

Comment: For me, there's no acceptable past participle for _wake_.  *_I have woken/woke/waked at 5am every day this week._ _Waken, awake,_ and _awaken_ forms don't mean the same thing, so I can't use them.

Comment: There’s also _quoth_ (only used in the first and third person simple past) and a few more in that vein, which my tired brain cannot recall. I’m surprised that _stridden_ is unnatural to so many; it’s perfectly natural to me. @John How does _awake_ differ from _wake_ in your example? “I [a]wake at 5 AM every day” means precisely the same thing with both verbs to me (and is, in both cases, a big fat lie; it’s nearly six now, and I’m still not even in bed). “I have awoken at 5 AM every day this week”  is what I would say, but I’d say “I awake at 5 AM” as well (or ‘wake up’ / ‘have woken up’).

Comment: @JohnLawler, I was raised hearing my mom say, "I've woken up before my alarm every day this week." She was particularly persnickety about language, fwiw. Not saying that means it's the only or the correct answer: just one that rings true for me.

Comment: This is the sort of thing that leads to local and idiosyncratic constructions. To me, _woken_ just doesn't sound right.