# Strings like 'open-minded': how are they classified?

Tags: grammar, participles, compound-adjectives

How are strings like 'open-minded' regarded?

If you say they're participles, I ask *of which verb* ('to open-mind' or 'to mind'? With which meaning then? Is there a meaning of 'to mind' like 'to provide a mind', 'to equip with a mind' or 'to have a mind'?). Or is it possible to form participles out of nouns with adjectives, too ('an open mind')?

Comment: Hello, Ben. This is partly a matter of looking up the word _open-minded_ in a dictionary. I think they all agree on the part of speech involved. // You could, after checking in a couple of dictionaries, say CD and AHD, look up 'participial adjectives' and 'compound adjectives' here on ELU. // Participial adjectives don't always have a corresponding verb.  // And compound adjectives formally similar to participial adjs may not be pa's. Related: [Is 'spellbind' a defective verb?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/360974/is-spellbind-a-defective-verb) (see especially herisson's answer).

Comment: Hello Edwin, thank you for your answer. I was aware of the existence of both participial adjectives (verb participles used as adjectives e.g. a closed door) and compound adjectives (more-than-one-term adjectives, e.g. not-so-easy stuff) but here we seem to have a combination of both species. This is why I have asked. Well, I was not aware of the fact that adjectives are ranked among participial ones even if they only look like participles and have no verb as base. Meanwhile - after your hint - I've had some more research and found a very simple example ('talented' with no verb 'to talent').

Comment: BenA. Alongside ***talented***, others that come immediately to mind are ***famed, renowned, diseased...*** And alongside ***open-minded*** are all those things like ***left-handed, po-faced, short-sighted.*** Though quite how to square that last one with the fact that ***far-sighted*** and ***far-seeing*** are both fine, whereas ***short-seeing*** doesn't seem to work, escapes me. (I expect @Edwin could answer that too, though! :)

Comment: At the risk of idosyncracy, isn't there a usage, according to which some nouns are treated as passive participles, modified by an (or, rather, another) adjective?  Examples would be 'bow-legged', 'two-faced', 'cack-handed', 'warm-hearted', 'copper-bottomed'...  In such instances, the word 'minded' is the the property of 'having a mind', then qualified by the property the mind has (in this case 'open') It is an example of the extreme flexibility of English that potentially any noun could be stretched in this way.  This is not a formally grammatical answer, but may show what is going on.

Comment: @Tuffy: Indeed. I'm not gonna bother checking to see whether there are any written references to *tight-skirted young ladies* in Google Books, but it sounds okay to me. On the other hand, ladies in *tight **skirts*** do seem somewhat more "accommodating"  than ladies in *tight **pants*** *(**tight-panted*** certainly doesn't seem to work, and ***tight-pantsed*** is completely beyond the pale).

Comment: @FF 'Po-facing' is possibly a euphemism for male. / Be content with sightseeing and sea-sighting (dubious) (as in the charabanc on the way to Blackpool).

Comment: @FumbleFingers Ah yes.  You obviously recognise that I am far from suggesting that ANY noun can sensibly emerge into the uplands of mor general use, though I can (being a Brit) refer to the ‘trousered Gaul’, even thought the cacophonous ‘pantsed Gaul’ would not do.

Comment: @Tuffy: Haha yeah - I reckon we're pretty much on the same page here. Both in matters linguistic *and* in our assumption of having the right/duty to be flippant towards cheese-eating surrender monkeys & others! Apropos which I was gonna cite our common origin in ***this sceptred isle*** as another example of an "adjectified noun" usage. But I just checked the full OED, and was a little surprised to find they actually have TWO DIFFERENT definitions for ***to sceptre*** as a VERB *(to **furnish** with a sceptre,* and *to **touch** with a sceptre as a sign of royal assent)*. Fascinating!

Comment: After all we are living in a ‘rhematc’ age:  one on which we can verb any noun.

Answer (score 1):

We must start with a reasonably precise definition of 'participial adjective'.

> **Identifying a Participial Adjective**
>
> The participial adjectives are a major subclass of adjectives. They
>   can be distinguished by their endings, usually either -ed or -ing.
>   Exceptions to this rule of thumb include *misunderstood* and
>   *unknown*, which function just like these other adjectives. They are called *participial adjectives* because they have the same endings as
>   verb participles. [Obviously, adjectives ending in ed or ing that are
>   not what we would class as -ed or -ing words, like *red*, are not in
>   this subclass.]
>
> **Function in a Sentence**
>
> These adjectives are really meant to function like any other
>   adjective: basically, they help to describe a noun. **They might come
>   from a verb form, or they might merely imitate the structure**, but
>   they always function as a descriptive adjective.

[from [YourDictionary.com; amended; bolding mine](https://grammar.yourdictionary.com/parts-of-speech/adjectives/what-is-a-participial-adjective.html)]

Note that there does not need to be a corresponding verb for a candidate to be classable as a participial adjective. OP himself has discovered *talented*, with no corresponding verb '[to] talent'. And note that 'They might come from a verb form ...' dismisses the possibility of back-formation of verb from adjective, which may well be a false assumption.

But does the class include *compound adjectives* where there is no corresponding compound verb (though there may be the corresponding simple verb)?
OP gives the example *open-minded*, where the simple verb 'mind' (and the participle 'minded') exists, but not the compound verb 'open-mind'.

The article includes *misunderstood* with the corresponding compound verb *misunderstand*, which causes no problems.

But it also includes the example 'unknown', with no corresponding 'unknow'.

Though classification requirements are always a matter of definition, it looks to be most sensible to consider *unknown, open-minded, open-mouthed, open-necked, action-packed, airheaded, middle-aged, widespread, windswept, eye-catching, death-defying, mind-boggling* and so on as (compound) participial adjectives, even though no directly corresponding verb exists. Even with *short-haired* and the like, where even the simple verb needs searching for. But now someone will ask "And having put them in a nice niche, where has that got you?"

Comment: This is a typically rigorous answer.  Are you sure that the this captures the specific nature of the question?  What I mean is that he is interested in a kind of compound adjective (for want of a better expression) involving something which cannot or at least is not a verb.  You are right that there is a verb 'to mind' with a passive participle (minded), which, however has an entirely different meaning.  'To mind' means 'to care', to look after' or 'to object to'.  'open-minded' means something quite different about the quality of someone's mind:  that they have an open mind.

Comment: No; I've given a reasonably scoped answer. OP asks about the [sub]class of words like 'open-minded'. Investigating whether particular examples are (a) formed by mimicry or (b) derive from an archaic/obsolete verb, and if (b) whether that verb was simple or itself compound, and whether the sense of that verb is retained in the compound participial adjective, I'll leave for some PhD student/s. Or perhaps you can find an article that some PhD students have already accomplished?

Comment: Hi! I've never believed that verbs like 'to open-mind' or 'to mind = to provide a mind' existed. It was clear to me that 'open-minded' is derived from the noun. So, you can see my first question as a rhetorical one. The core of my questions was if a word created by putting a noun and -ed together can be called a participle. It obviously can if you call it a participial adjective when using it as an adjective. Now I'm pondering how such a participle could be called. We can hardly call it 'past participle' as nouns have no time component...I know. This participle is probably not defined so far.

Comment: Some more research later... The Wikipedia article [Participle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Participle) says that a participle is a verb form and that it's called like that because the verb shares or __participates__ in noun/adjective features like declension. If participating is what makes a participle then noun+ed is perfectly applicable. This noun form obviously feels like a verb form ('to talent' = 'to provide a talent'). It looks like a noun participates in being a verb. Eureka! A noun participle! The missing link! Perhaps the participle definition shouldn't exclude nouns...

Comment: Hopefully, there never have been and never will be verbs such as po-face, bow-leg, mean-spirit and windsweep. Here, mimicry (of form) and similar behaviour (modifying a noun) suffice to label these words as participial adjectives. 'looks and behaves like mainstream participial adjectives', not 'a verb form', is the definition of 'participial' needed in 'participial adjective' to accommodate things without a corresponding verb.

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth The question is why 'mimicry (of form) and similar behaviour (modifying a noun)' does not suffice to label these forms officially as participles. I don't see why - as I have written before. This would bring a piece of grammatical clearness as each participial adjective would be called so because the word used for this function would be for itself a participle - not only looking like one. In my opinion, it would be a good and useful specification even though not a vital one. Perhaps some linguist picks it up one day.

Comment: There is at least one other common construction in which a non-verb takes an apparently participial ending. I am talking about the suffix "-en" in "wooden", "earthen", "golden", etc. Those words also function adjectivally, but I would not consider them to be past participles.

Comment: @MarcInManhattan Yes, this is a clear derivation from a _noun_ [[Online Etymological Dictionary](https://www.etymonline.com/word/wooden)] with the adjectivising suffix -en added. Oaken, oaten, wool[l]en .... We sadly seem to have lost beanen ('made of beans').